# Split string with Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

We have a CSV file. A specific column was to have many entries and those were to be separated with a newline character `"\n"`, which didn't happen. Sample data of the affected column are as follows.

```
30 units - R135                 50 units - R225                  80 units - R360
```

Is there a method to split this into three columns? The number of columns is not fixed. I guess we will have to use many space characters (more than two) to `split` entries. I need:

```
data = "that long string"
# Some operation
result = ["30 units - R135", "50 units - R225", "80 units - R360"]
```

I tried some thing like this. But it didn't work. The result was the same string.

```
a.split('/(\s){3,}/')
```

What approach could be taken to split the data?

Comment: It works for me if you get rid of the single quotes and make it a regex literal.  My guess is that ruby is interpreting your regex as a literal string.  Try a.split(/(\s){3,}/) instead.

Comment: You can't possibly get that result from `that long string`. Please show real inputs and outputs; people won't try to guess what your data looks like.

Comment: Of course it didn't have a newline, that's normally the end of record character in csv.   If it was in the data, it would have to be escaped first.

Comment: @CodeGnome The long string is given above. It was the output of the CSV library that the project uses. All columns were red which were 23 and will be too much to put over here. The output of the reg ex I used `resulted the same string`. I could have been clear, but I thought it was sufficient.

Comment: @Jeremy I thought you have to give a string to the split function. I never thought your example would work. Its the first time we are working in Ruby. Getting used to has been a little difficult. Monday is a demo :) I will check it out and thanks.

Comment: @DGM: There is no *"of course"*. Newlines are quite acceptable within quote-delimited fields.

Comment: @Jeremy I tried it in the console, it works. The issue was with the quote marks. I thought it was taking a string pattern. Thanks for the info. Wish you had put a simple answer to accept. So I will go with what I already given an an up vote for you guys. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jeremy: The parentheses are unnecessary in that pattern, and will cause a single space character to be stored in `$1`

Comment: @DGM We were aware of it and the specific field was having quotes. I am sorry I have missed to include it in the question

Comment: @CodeGnome: It is reasonably clear what the OP means if you read the question. `that long string` refers to the string referred to as *"Sample data of the affected column"* a couple of lines previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A statement like

```
a.split('/(\s){3,}/')
```

will split the string in `a` at occurrences of the *string* `/(\s){3,}/`, which (unsurprisingly) occurs nowhere in the target string, so it remains instact.

You need to specify a regexp by writing

```
data = '30 units - R135                 50 units - R225                  80 units - R360'

result = data.split /\s{3,}/

p result
```

**output**

```
["30 units - R135", "50 units - R225", "80 units - R360"]
```

Answer (score 2):

the correct regex for this is:

`a.split(/\s{3,}/)`

a nice place to try out regex expressions:
http://rubular.com/ (you may not need it , but i love it too much so sharing :) )

Comment: The OP said he wanted to split the string on *"more than two"* space characters. Two is not more than two, so the pattern was correct in the first place.

Comment: @Borodin , sorry i misread the question , updated the answer accordingly.